# WebApplicationException is not showing the error message

Tags: jax-rs, cxf

I created my custom exception class by extending WebApplicationException class of jax-rs api. I am throwing this exception on wrong inputs.

```
public class RestException extends WebApplicationException {

    public RestException(String message, Response.Status status) {
        super(message, status);
    }


}
```

When I used above exception in my application, it is returning the status code correctly, but it is not returning the error message i set in the constructor.

If i use jersey instead of cxf, it is showing both error message and status code. Any help on this....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get rid of the problem by changing the signature of RestException constructore like below.

```
public class RestException extends WebApplicationException {

    public RestException(String message, Response.Status status) {
        super(Response.status(status).entity(message).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build());
    }


}
```